# Launch activity only when app first is installed and opened?

Tags: android, android-activity, installation, sharedpreferences, launch

I am having trouble fixing this flow of my application. I have created learning pages for the users these pages should be shown only when users open the application for the first time.

I used shared preferences to do that, it works except when I closed the app permanently from the recent list applications these pages launched again when I open the application.

What to do ? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Shared Preferences in Android When app is first open store that these pages are visited and then after reOpen donot allow to open these pages. 
Or you can use Sqlite DataBase to store the reference of the app open and when relaunch the app check the Database

Comment: Can you provide me piece of code for more explanation ?

Comment: I mean how to do it using Sqlite Database?

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out how to do it with Sqlite database. I create new table in database with only one raw for the Flag which is equal to 0. then I update it to 1 when it enters to the activity that I only wants to run for once at a time

Comment: Ok.No problem i am happy to help others.Still if you want tutorial on how to use sql lite database you can comment here.